# How can hide full path of my webpage in Ubuntu at DigitalOcean?

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04

Good day: I have my domain, for example: www.mydomain.cl in Digital Ocean (hosting) with Ubuntu, hosting. In this path I have my wordpress files:

```
/var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1
```

My 000-default.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have one page for example called "quienes-somos" so I can enter like this in the browser:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1/quienes-somos/
```

My home page is:

```
/var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1/index.php
```

So I enter in the browser as follows:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1
```

I just want to hide full path of my pages, for example, instead of showing in the browser this:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1/quienes-somos/
```

I want to be shown as:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/quienes-somos/
```

I am confused to achieve that, please let me know if any clarification is required, Could anyone help me, please? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1 ? (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Is /alianzaWordpress/datos1/ a directory on your server? If it is then setting your docuemnt root to DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1 will let you achieve the effect you require. Your URL's will show as http://www.mydomain.cl/quienes-somos/ followed by the downstream directory and page names.

Comment: Dear Smock and Sridhar, you are the best, finally it worked, thank you so much, and sorry for such as basic question, regards from Chile :)